# Working with javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, spring-data

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379605/how-to-work-with-javax-persistence-sql-load-script-source) about schema data initialization for EclipseLink, and I want to achieve the same in Spring Data JPA.

The answers all assume the presence of a `persistence.xml` file, which I am not using.

Instead I have Spring config, as follows:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="rbf.staffing.data"/>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
            <entry key="eclipselink.id-validation" value="NULL"/>
            <entry key="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <entry key="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="main/resources/import.sql" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Where `jpaVendorAdapter` is a `EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter`.

All the DDL works great, but the `import.sql` is not being executed. It is in `src/main/resources`

Comment: May be you can find the solution in [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379605/how-to-work-with-javax-persistence-sql-load-script-source)

Comment: that's the same question I linked to

Comment: Set logging to finest and it should print out a message or an exception if the issue is because it cannot find the import.sql.  Make sure the directory specified is relative to where the persistence unit it as defined from where the meta-inf/persistence.xml 'would' be located.  I'm guessing you should just define "import.sql" depending on how it is packaged.